# How to get a user specific configuration value, or default if missing, in a single SQL

Tags: sql

I have a configuration table, that holds the values selected by a specific user. If no values where entered, then the default should be returned. But there's a catch: the user belong to a speciffic group, and each group has it's own defaul.

What I need is *a single query* that returns the user's values, or the default for his/her group if no data found.

The config tables structure is quite simple:

```
CONFIGURATION: ConfigurationId (PK), GroupId (FK), UserId (FK), ConfigurationDetailId (FK);
CONFIGURATIONDETAIL: ConfigurationDetailId (PK), ConfigValue1, ConfigValue2
```

A user may belong to more than one group, and have different configurations for each. Those configs are considered different (have their own ConfigurationDetailId) even if their values are the same.
When I look for the data, I always have the GroupId and the UserId

This works, but I wanted something more "elegant"... What I don't like is the TOP 1 and ORDER BY I need to eliminate the default row when a user specific row exists:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  FROM Config C
 WHERE C.GroupId = @GroupId
   AND (C.UserId = @UserId OR C.UserId IS NULL)
 ORDER BY C.UserId DESC
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data structure? It appears this query should be fine...

Comment: What do you consider to be more "elegant"? Something backwards with 2 less characters, like `AND @UserID = COALESCE(c.UserID, @UserID)`?

Comment: [Define Elegant](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/conversation/define-elegant)

Comment: `This works, but I wanted something more "elegant"...` I have found in my years that great programmers are lazy, whereas good programmers want to emulate that lazy and find themselves overworking things. When you have a solution that is a) readable, b) works, c) doesn't have side effects, and it didn't take you ten hours to write, then you've been lazy enough to be effective. I wouldn't try any harder than you have. I would also call a five line query that does what I needed "elegant". Cheers!

Comment: @AaronBertrand et all, What I don't like of my solution is the TOP 1 and ordering I use to eliminate the default row...

Comment: So can you show sample data and desired results with a userid that has their own default and a userid that doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try a self join, depending on your table structure.

```
create table config
 ( GroupID int, 
   UserID int, 
   ConfigId int, 
   ConfigValue varchar(50),
   IsDefault int );

insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, NULL, 1, 'A', 1);
insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, NULL, 2, 'B', 1);
insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, NULL, 3, 'C', 1);
insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, 1, 1, 'A1', 0);
insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, 1, 2, 'B1', 0);
insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, 1, 3, 'C1', 0);
insert into config (groupid, userid, configid, configvalue, isdefault)
values (1, 2, 1, 'A2', 0);

select 
   COALESCE(c1.configid, c2.configid) as configid,
   COALESCE(c1.configvalue, c2.configvalue) as configvalue
from config c1 right join config c2
 on (c1.groupid = c2.groupid 
     and c1.configid = c2.configid
     and c1.isdefault = 0 and c1.userid = 2)
where c2.isdefault = 1 and c2.groupid = 1;

select 
   COALESCE(c1.configid, c2.configid) as configid,
   COALESCE(c1.configvalue, c2.configvalue) as configvalue
from config c1 right join config c2
 on (c1.groupid = c2.groupid 
     and c1.configid = c2.configid
     and c1.isdefault = 0 and c1.userid = 1)
where c2.isdefault = 1 and c2.groupid = 1;
```

Results for userid = 2

```
CONFIGID    CONFIGVALUE
1           A2
2           B
3           C
```

Results for userid = 1

```
CONFIGID    CONFIGVALUE
1           A1
2           B1
3           C1
```

I've built a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d519e/1) for this so you can see it for yourself.

Comment: Extensive answer, though it does not fit the standard scientific definition of "elegant" :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and fiddle! +1 for that! Indeed seems more complicated than mine, but it's probably the correct answer to my question. I'll see if someone else posts a different answer for a while and select this as such if not.

Comment: @swasheck This is a "elegant" way if you think of this from a "set" perspective - rather than resorting to `TOP` and `ORDER BY`, I use a self join on the table to arrive at a set that is the answer, rather than a set that has bad data in that I ignore.

Comment: @NWest fair enough. I appreciated your answer and was more just getting a chuckle from the nondescript use of "elegant"